# How can I replicate an Oracle 11g database(data+structure) on my local machine for development?

Tags: oracle, database, oracle11g

I am working on a test server with an Oracle 11g installed. I was wondering if there is anyway I can replicate the database(environment + data) on my local Linux machine. I am using a CentOS 5.3 on Windows XP with SUN Virtual Box. On Windows I am using sqldeveloper client to connect to the 11g database.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of ways to move the data over:

- Restore an RMAN backup on your test server
- Export and import the data using exp/expdp/imp/impdp
- Export and import using a transportable tablespace ([Further Info](http://psoug.org/reference/tts.html))
- Use database links to duplicate the data using SQL

Comment: I always like the "Restore from RMAN backup" option. It's a great way to ensure that your know how to...restore a backup. You know, in case you have to do that one day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the Database Configuration Assistant](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28301/install003.htm#BABEIAID) to generate a template from your production  database.  This will give you all the parameters and tablespaces, among other things.  You will need to tweak the configuration somewhat; for instance  the file paths may be wrong, and some parameters may need downsizing.  You can then feed that template into DBCA to clone the database on you Linux machine.

To get the schemas and data you should use [Data Pump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/dp_overview.htm#i1009203) (rather than the older Import / Export utlities).  This can be run off the command line or from [PL/SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_datpmp.htm#i1007277).

Bear in mind that using production data in a development or test environment can cause you to run foul of data protection laws and other compliance issues.  It depends on what your application does and what jurisdiction you operate under.  But if your production system contains citizens' personal data you need to be very careful.  There are products out there which will apply masking as part of a data import process (Oracle sells one) but they tend to be expensive.  Rolling your own masking product can be tricky: if this applies to your situation be sure to get your compliance staff (legal team) involved early.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you install Oracle XE which is free to use on your local if your development is not something that is related to core database features. You can then use the methods given above to pump data into Oracle XE and compile your code on it, though for development I don't think you would need data as much as that in production.